# MSSQL Import/Export/Copy IDENTITY_INSERT problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008.
I have a db (say ip 10.16.17.10 and called **db1**) and a second one (say ip 10.16.17.25 called **db2**).

I am trying to copy one **table** (and its contents) from **db1** into **db2**.
I have the database on both (but empty in db2).

The problem is no matter how I copy/export/import, no matter what options I set in **MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008** when I click 'table'->'Design' (on **db2**) it ALWAYS says '**Identity Spefication**: NO' even tho the db1 table has it on.

From **db1** I go to 'Tasks'->'export'->'source/db' and 'destination/db'->'Edit Mapping'->'Enable identity Insert' and click it on.

But no joy. ALWAYS exports without it.
I try similar thing from IMPORT on **db2**. Similar thing if I use COPY.

I have read MANY of the STACKOVERFLOW articles on this, they all suggest setting IDENTITY_INSERT setting to ON but when I do run below:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ON
```

The table either doesn't exist yet or has already copied WITHOUT the identity setting on so see the error:

```
does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.
```

I have tried setting it as a property (under database properties) for **db2** but when I copy/import/export never works.

Would appreciate any help here as lots of StackOverflow articles so far all seem to be having an easier time than me.

I am planning on doing this for another 50 or so tables in this database so am hoping to find a way which doesnt involve running scripts for each table.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process of using the Export Data Wizard to copy the data from one table to another will NOT replicate all aspects of the schema (like identity and auto-increment). If you want to replicate the schema, script out your table into a create statement, change the name to db2, and create it. Then you should be able to run the export/import wizard with the identity insert option on and insert into your new table that replicates the schema of your old table.

Comment: hey, yep i have been grabbing the create table script for each in DB1 and then copying the values with IMPORT DATA...is there a faster way to do this with Management Studio? currently I am 'Script Table As'->'Create To'->'Query Editor' for each table (running each one in DB2), but there are about 100 tables and it will take a long time like this

Comment: There's a few different options for that. The quickest for you, if you have SQL Server Data Tools or Visual Studio Data Tools load it up and look under the SQL menu for a schema compare.

Comment: so you would suggest not using MS SQL Server Management Studio for this? unfortunately its all i have right now :(

Comment: You could also right click on the database and under tasks you'll find generate scripts for database objects option. You can select the objects you want to script there.

Comment: By the way, VS Data Tools is free, and will run on top of either VS2010 or VS2012 shell (also free) - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/13/available-today-ssdt-december-2012.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29

Answer (score 3):

Ended up sorting this out using MS SQL Management Studio.

Thanks to @kevin for the help regarding Import Data and Export Data. Schemas are NOT transferred across however they are the best means to transport the data once schema is up.

Found best way to MASS import/export db table schemas using below (Saved SQL create scripts to file):

**Tasks->Generate Scripts->All Tables To File->with Identity on**

Ran 200kb SQL file on **db2** for schema.

Then ran **Import Data** from **db1** to **db2**.

Done, all Identity_Inserts maintained.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Error message](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/cannot-perform-set-operation/) I think your table *does not* have an `IDENTITY` column. Make sure that `[dbo].[mytable]` does have an `IDENTITY column` before you executing `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ON
```

[DEMO1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebbb0/1) (Trying to set identity ON when there is ***NO identity column***)

```
--Error    
'Table 'T' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.: SET IDENTITY_INSERT T ON'
```

[DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e37/1) (Trying to set identity ON when there ***is identity column***)

```
--No Errors
```

Comment: sorry its not an identity column...its for AUTO INCREMENT...I need the IDENTITY_INSERT property to be ON (for this table) and its copies/exports/imports as OFF. What you have printed is exactly what I printed above. I am confused.

Comment: @CraigTaub, I didn't change anything in code wise. Important thing is the message. I don't understand why you down vote? You can `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF` on an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: because it didnt explain anything and u copied what I already had...If i am copy/export/import the table exactly as it is, why does it not have the identity property for the column?

Comment: thanks for the DEMOs, the problem is I need to copy all 100 or so tables over and get them to keep the IDENTITY part in the 'create table' script...I am aware that the IDENTITY part needs to be run with the create table but i have been asking why copy/import/export doesnt include that in create table script and how else i can do it for mass tables

Comment: You need to understand what my message says. I didn't ask you to try that way or this way with a new code. What I said was to SET IDENTITY ON/OFF off, that table should have an IDENTITY column. Otherwise you will get that error message.

Comment: You cant use SET IDENTITY ON/OFF until you have actually exported identity property successfully. Its waste

Answer (score 1):

Follow following Steps :

From db1 I go to 'Tasks'->'export'->'source/db' and 'destination/db'->'Edit Mapping'->'Enable identity Insert' and Edit SQL - > You will able to see query structure of Table.

IN the query for eg. ID int NOT NULL, do the next step ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
Then proceed.

I bet it will work.

Comment: hey rick, is there anyway to get this to work if I select 100 tables in the 'Select source Tables' list?

Comment: Yes u can, while u select 100 tables u can edit mapping of each and every table. While every tables are selected just click on each one and go to edit mapping and follow above steps.

Comment: VERY long to have to do that for 150 odd tables....ok thanks... disappointed MS SQL Management Studio cant handle something as trivial as this easily..

Comment: Well since yesterday i was fighting with this issue and solved myself for hardly 20 tables. Hope this helps you.. Vote up the answer if problem is solved. Thanks :)